# iPhone MKMapView commercial application?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

Can I create an iOS commercial application (a couple of dollars to download in appstore) using the MKMApView component?

I know it is based on Google images so... I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, MapKit is used in thousands of commercial apps. You can read the terms of service [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html) if you want to look into it further.

Comment: I think you have to include a link to those terms in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can't do turn-by-turn based directions using MapKit - I believe Google's TOC restricts that.  Chances are that Apple wouldn't let you put that app past the review process anyhow...

Answer (score 0):

Yep, my app is a paid app that uses MKMapView. However, I cannot use Google's geocoding service to get the lat/lon of a street address without paying for a Google Maps API license since I would be using it from a non-free app.